# mysql wont start after increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_log_file_size

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

I am following this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#comment14041132_4056261 and tried to increase my `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 4G and later 1G (also 1024M) in addition to the log file size, but mysql wont start with those values.
If I put it back to 512M mysql starts fine.

How can I solve this? My server is a 16GB one, and according to Webmin sysinfo:

```
Real memory 15.62 GB total, 3.13 GB used
```

Meanwhile I found the error log as well:

> 120529 10:29:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
>
> 120529 10:29:33 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /var/lib/mysql
>
> 120529 10:29:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 120529 10:29:33 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 120529 10:29:33 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 120529 10:29:33 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 120529 10:29:33 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>
> 120529 10:29:33 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
>
> 120529 10:29:33 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 134217728
>   bytes
>
> InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 268435456 bytes!

Comment: Can you please share the error logs for that...

Comment: Thanks, I managed to find it. I think this will be easier. I should have also added initially that I increased the log file size as well to match the increase in the buffer pool (I did add this info now).

Comment: Ok @giorgio79...

Comment: Try to delete the log file(s).

Comment: Did you delete log file size first? did you drop all the databases first? Please add more info about what did you do exactly?

Comment: For information i can say in MySQL 5.6.10 this issue does not occur. Recent MySQL is detecting automatically the log file size and there is no need to stop + delete log files + start server.
Thats great ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The two answers given from [**@RickJames**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18538/877) and [**@drogart**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18537/877) are essentially the remedies. (+1 for each).

Right from the error log you present, the last two lines say:

> InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 134217728 bytes
>
> InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 268435456 bytes! `

At that point, it was evident that you set [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) to 256M (268435456) in `my.cnf` while the InnoDB Transaction Logs (`ib_logfile0`,`ib_logfile1`) were respectively 128M (134217728) each. Looking back at the [**link to my StackOverflow answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056261/491757) in your question, you had to do the following:

Step 01) Add this to `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_log_file_size=1G
```

Step 02) Run these command in the OS

```
mysql -u... -p... -e"SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 1"
service mysql stop
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*
service mysql start
```

So as to have confidence in what is happening, run `tail -f` against the error log. You will see message telling you when each innodb log file is being created.

Comment: Thanks, yep I did not delete them first. Just wanted to see how mysql behaves. After performing step 3 restarting worked.

Comment: I think one shouldn't delete the log files, but rather move them elsewhere, and delete them a while later when you've successfully changed the log file size. Otherwise, you'd be in trouble if MySQL crashed before you ran `service mysqld stop`.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error in the log, I'm guessing you did this:

- shut down mysql
- edited my.cnf to change the innodb log file size
- tried to start mysql (then it failed)

If you change the log file size, you need to remove the old log files.  Innodb will not start successfully if the existing files do not match the specified size in the config file.  If you move them elsewhere, innodb will create new transaction log files of the correct size when it starts.

I would recommend moving the old files to another directory instead of just deleting them, until the server is up and running with new log files and everything looks OK.

Answer (score 3):

The buffer_pool should be set to about 70% of *available* RAM if you are running InnoDB only.

The log size does not matter a lot.   The optimal is to set it so that  (Uptime * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written) is *roughly* 3600 (1 hour).

To change the log size, one must

1. shut down mysqld cleanly
2. delete the value in my.cnf (my.ini)
3. delete the log files
4. retstart -- new log files will be rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is a correct answer as well. I could only accept one though. +1d this too.

Answer (score 2):

***There can also be some issue in your value provided for buffer pool size***. like it happened in my case...

When increasing or decreasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, the operation is performed in chunks. Chunk size is defined by the `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` configuration option, which has a default of 128M. For more information, see *Configuring InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size*.

Buffer pool size must always be equal to or a multiple of `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances`. If you configure `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to a value that is not equal to or a multiple of `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances`, buffer pool size is automatically adjusted to a value that is equal to or a multiple of `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances` that is not less than the specified buffer pool size.

In the example, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set to 8G, and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is set to 16. `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` is 128M, which is the default value.

8G is a valid `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value because 8G is a multiple of `innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16 * innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=128M`, which is 2G.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with the size you chosen to increase the logs by.

In my example Confluence recommends a log size of 2GB but when I made this change, even if I delete the old logfiles the service will not start. I reduced it down to 1GB in size and the service started without any issues...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. here is my error log...

```
221123 05:05:40 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /www/server/data
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 107374182400 adjusted to 1073741824
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Note] /www/server/mysql/bin/mariadbd (server 10.7.3-MariaDB-log) starting as process 2185 ...
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 268435456, chunk size = 134217728
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=42227,42227
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT at 42227 between the checkpoint 42227 and the end 98966.
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-11-23  5:05:40 0 [ERROR] Aborting
221123 05:05:40 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /www/server/data/##VM-HOST-NAME##.pid ended
```

I changed the `max_allowed_packet` to `1073741824` in the config file, deleted the `ib_logfile0` log file, and then restarted the SQL server.
It's solved my problem.

Comment: I think you're just saying the accepted answer works. Yes?

Comment: Yes. I can't upvote the correct answer since I don't have enough reputation. :(