# Issue after moving the ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0 files

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

I wanted to increase the `innodb_log_file_size` for better performance. And I increased it from the default value to 256 MB. As usual I got the error saying `InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes`. So I moved these files to different location and restarted the MySQL server. It worked. Before shutting down the MySQL, server I also made `innodb_fast_shutdown  =  0`.

But I have a doubt, after MySQL shutdown can we expect mysql is an consistent state and all the data that were in the `ib_logfile0  and ib_logfile1` have been written to data files. So that I can delete these files or should I do something else also.

And if the answer is MySQL will be in consistent state than why these files contain some data even after graceful shutdown and start up with `innodb_fast_shutdown  =  0`.

### [EDIT details]  giving the steps i have done

> Steps i followed:
>
> 1. SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0
> 2. /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
> 3. rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
> 4. rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
> 5. /etc/init.d/mysqld start

Is the above step is fine? if yes then how come after the clean shutdown and start up the log files contains some data. Ideally it should be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you coming to the conclusion that "these files contain some data even after graceful shutdown"?

Even if it's been fully flushed and uncommitted transactions cleared, etc., by using `innodb_fast_shutdown = 0`, the "flushing" probably means that the file is "empty" as far as MySQL is concerned, but it won't physically be full of zeroes.

If you start MySQL up again, it will probably zip through the files to the latest Log Sequence Number and realise that there's no more work to be done (someone familiar with the source code that handles the innodb logs would be able to confirm/deny this).

Your steps should be absolutely fine, but I'd take [Baron Schwartz's suggestion](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/07/09/how-to-change-innodb_log_file_size-safely/) and move the ib_logfiles somewhere instead of deleting them, just in case it turns out that the server doesn't shut down cleanly for some reason.

Comment: when i set innodb_fast_shutdown =0 and did a shutdown and start mysql, i tried open the ib_logfile0 file and found it was not empty rather something in binary format was still present. Thats why i asked the question. please clarify.

Comment: Imagine that you have a piece of paper where you've written down a list of books that you want to read (in order), and then you go and read them all. If you decide to make a new list, it doesn't matter if you use the same paper or not... if you use the same piece of paper, you'll just look through your list and think "read that one, read that one..." until you get to one you haven't read. In the same way, the ib_logfile doesn't need to be zeroed out - the database can figure out what it's written and what it hasn't - but (if it was shut down properly) it also doesn't matter if it's not there.

Answer (score 3):

The steps you outlined are correct.

I have written about this before

- `Feb 16, 2011` : [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1265/877)
- `May 30, 2012` : [mysql wont start after increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_log_file_size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18553/877)

Doing `innodb_fast_shutdown = 1` is incomplete because ibdata1 still have other transactional tidbits that will cleanup during the Crash Recovery phase of the next restart of mysqld. Some data changes may not make it.

Doing [`innodb_fast_shutdown = 0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fast_shutdown) is a complete flush of all InnoDB transactional changes in the Log Files and in ibdata1 (See [**Pictorial Representation**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)).

Therefore, please do not change anything you have stated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small problem in your approach, if I understood correctly, you changed the log file size, and restarted MySQL with `innodb_fast_shutdown = 0`. The problem here is that you still have some transaction on log files that aren't in the ibdata. What you need to do is tell MySQL to write all changes from log files to ibdata before move the log files, see bellow

1. Change `innodb_fast_shutdown` to 0
2. Restart MySQL - it will make MySQL start with `innodb_fast_shutdown = 0`
3. Stop MySQL - it will force MySQL to write all changes remaining on log files to ibdata
4. Change the value for `innodb_log_file_size` and return `innodb_fast_shutdown = 1`
5. Move old log files to some place else
6. Start MySQL

Following these steps you will make sure all remaining changes will be wrote to ibdata before create the new log files.

Comment: innodb_fast_shutdown is a dynamic variable, so you should be able to save yourself a restart and set it using `set global innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;`, then proceed with steps 3, 5, and 6. The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html) indicates that `innodb_fast_shutdown = 1` should be fine, and it probably is, but it just *feels* like it should be set to 0.